# Return Lastname when not definded

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined

I'm studying JavaScript combining functions. Supposed I have `firstname`
and `lastName` as two arguments of my function. I want the console to display `Doe` when `lastname` is `undefinded` . Here is my code but it printed out undefined. Any idea? Thank you!

```
let name = 'John'

function greetByDefault(firstname,lastname){
     return 'Hi ' + firstname +' '+ lastname + '!';
 }
  if (lastname === undefined){
        return 'Doe';
 }

console.log(greetByDefault('Jane', 'Doe'));
console.log(greetByDefault(name));
```

I want the console output to be:

Hi Jane Doe!
Hi John Doe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put everything in `function`

```
let name = 'John'
function greetByDefault(firstname,lastname){
  if (lastname === undefined){
      lastname = 'Doe';
  }
     return 'Hi ' + firstname +' '+ lastname + '!';
 }

console.log(greetByDefault('Jane', 'Doe'));
console.log(greetByDefault(name));
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like this using a default value

```js
let name = 'John'

function greetByDefault(firstname,lastname = 'Doe'){
     return 'Hi ' + firstname +' '+ lastname + '!';
 }
 

console.log(greetByDefault('Jane', 'Doe'));
console.log(greetByDefault(name));
console.log(greetByDefault(name, 'Smith'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = 'John'
function greetByDefault(firstname,lastname=''){
 if (lastname== ''){
    lastname =  'Doe';
  }
return 'Hi ' + firstname +' '+ lastname + '!';

}
console.log(greetByDefault('Jane', 'Doe'));
console.log(greetByDefault(name));
```